# ChartJS - How to use x,y points in bar chart

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I see in the [docs](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html#data-structure), you can specify x,y coordinates when using the time scale.

I'm wondering if I can do this using a different scale. I have 10 categories that I would like to place my x points in and then sum up the y values for each group of x 's.

My x categories are `0-10`, `10-20`, `20-30`, .... `90-100` with a total of 10 categories.

For instance - point(15, 1923) will go in Bin 2, and the value of the bar will be all of the y values in bin 2.